# int array in java wont contain expected value

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I want that my array num cosist of each char from my string b
like this:

```
num[0] = 9;
num[1] = 1;
num[2] = 1;
num[3] = 9;
```

but somehow the 9 turns into a 57 and the 1 turns into 1. I dont get why. When i print out `b.charAt(i)` the numbers are correct but as soon as i try to initialze the array the numbers change.
I also tried to cast with `(int)b.charAt(i)` but that didnt make a difference.
why do the numbers change ?

```
int a = 9119;
String b = a+"";
System.out.println(b);
int [] num = new int[b.length()];
String c = "";

for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(b.charAt(i));
    num[i] = b.charAt(i);
    //c += (num[i] * num[i])+"";System.out.println(c);
}
for (int w : num)
{
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

this is the console outprint:

```
9119
9
1
1
9
57
49
49
57
```

Comment: The integer 9 and the ascii character "9" are not the same, as you have discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line `num[i] = b.charAt(i);` you are basically converting the character `9` to its decimal representation, which is `57`. The same is true for `1` which decimal representation is `49`.

If you turn your `int[] num` into `char[] num` everything works as expected. Additionally, use `String.valueOf()` to convert an `int` into a `String`:

```java
int a = 9119;
String b = String.valueOf(a);
System.out.println(b);
char[] num = new char[b.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(b.charAt(i));
    num[i] = b.charAt(i);
}

for (char w : num) {
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

note that the char '9' is different from the int 9,

```
char a = '9'; 
int b = a;
```

for code like this, it will auto-cast the char '9' into int by the ASCII code of the letter '9', in the ASCII table, '9' is the 57th letter, so the auto-cast will let our int b assigned to the value 57. similar idea for char '1', int ASCII table, the number is 49.